# Deploying Node App with bcrypt dependency on AWS ElasticBeanstalk fails

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, node-modules

I am running into problems deploying a node app with bcrypt as a dependency on AWS Elastic BeanStalk. I have checked the eb-engine.log file and i get the error message below

[image: Error Log]

I have added the  `"unsafe-perm":true` as part of the config options in my package.json and also added `unsafe-perm=true`in my .npmrc file.

Is there something i am doing wrong? Kindly assist.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the bcrypt-nodejs library.

> npm install --save bcrypt-nodejs && npm uninstall --save bcrypt